# Token name for website login via python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to sign into a website using Python's requests library. I've ever used it before, but I think the only place I'm stuck is the token. In the website's login Form Data the token name is "idsrv.xsrf". The problem is that I can't use this as a keyword in the dictionary because of the period.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as r:
url = "https://www.foo.com/login"
USERNAME = "uname"
PASSWORD = "pword"
r.get(url)
token=r.cookies["idsrv.xsrf"]
login_data = dict(idsrv.xsrf=token, Username=USERNAME, Password=PASSWORD)
r.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://login.foo.com/login"})
page = r.get("https://www.foo.com/Home")
print(page.content)
```

I've tried pluging in idsrv, xsrv, idsrv_xsrv.  When I do any of those it gives me the page content of the login page rather than that of the home page. I believe that this is my only issue, but I won't know for sure until it's solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the other method of instantiating a dictionary:

```
login_data = {'idsrv.xsrf':token, 'Username':USERNAME, 'Password':PASSWORD}
```

Interesting backstory about the performance differences here: https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/